# Use a custom colourscheme in Vim

Tags: vim, colors

I have customized a color profile for Vim (toto.vim) in the colors folder at : `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors`

Now, to use it, I am obliged to call it each time I start vim, using the command :

```
:colorscheme toto
```

Is there any way to load it by default instead of the default color scheme?

Comment: Does this help at all: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim/.vimrc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `.vimrc` file in your $HOME to load commands whenever you start vim.

```
vim $HOME/.vimrc
```

Just put your command as one line; commands in the `.vimrc` are used in ex-mode, so you don't need to put the colon at the beginning (so use `colorscheme toto` rather than `:colorscheme toto`).

You can find plenty of example `.vimrc`s online with lots of neat tricks in them, too.

Comment: That is what I have done. I appended colorscheme toto in the /usr/share/vim/vimrc   and now it's working fine. Thanks. I am validating your answer in few seconds!

Comment: Appending it to /usr/share/vim/vimrc will force it on every other user of vim on your computer and might get you into trouble if /usr/share/vim/vimrc is controlled by your package manager. $HOME/.vimrc does not have these issues.

Comment: Yeah thanks. The purpose was to force the same layout for all users!